# матрица смежности реберного графа

Tags: c++, графы

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда я составляю матрицу смежности реберного графа из матрицы инцидентности в ней последняя строка и последний столбец остаются заполненные 0? В чем ошибка? Ввожу ребра 12,23,34,45,15,24 [image: что должно быть]

```
  struct EdgeArray {
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
};
int main()
{
    int Graph[100][100], Vertex, Edge, x, y;
    EdgeArray mass[100];
    int Incidence[100][100];
    cout << "Enter number of vertexes:";
    cin >> Vertex;
    cout << "\nEnter number of edges:";
    cin >> Edge;
    //FILL NULL Adjacency matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < Vertex; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Vertex; j++)
        {
            Graph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    //FILL NULL Incidence Matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Vertex; j++)
        {
            Incidence[i][j] = 0;
        }
    //INPUT EDGES
    cout << "\nEnter edges:\n " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
    {
        cout << "e1=";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "e2=";
        cin >> y;
        cout << endl;
        Graph[x][y] = 1;
        Graph[y][x] = 1;

        mass[i].x =x ; // struct massive input data
        mass[i].y =y ;
    }
    //OUTPUT
    cout << "\nAdjacency matrix:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Vertex; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <Vertex; j++)
        {
            cout <<"  "<< Graph[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    //

    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++) {
        Incidence[i][mass[i].x] = 1; // incidence matrix
        Incidence[i][mass[i].y] = 1;
 }


    //OUTPUT
    cout << "\nIncidence Matrix:\n" << endl;
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Vertex; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++)
        {
            cout << "  " << Incidence[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nAdjacency matrix of Edge Graph:\n";
    int AR[100][100];
    for (int v = 0;v<Vertex;v++)
    for (x = 0; x <Vertex;x++)
        if (Incidence[v][x])
             for (y =x+1; y <Edge; y++)
                  if (Incidence[v][y]) {
                      AR[x][y] = 1;
                      AR[y][x] = 1;
                  }
    for (int v = 1; v < Edge; v++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Edge; j++)
        {
            cout << "  " << AR[v][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

[image: результат]

Comment: в циклах условие окончания неверное...

Comment: в смысле? можно поподробнее?

Comment: в Си индексы масивов начинаются от нуля и идут до `N-1`, так что циклы обычно имеют вид `for (x = 0; x <Vertex;x++)`... всё остальное — расточительно или чертовски подозрительно... Но это не основная ошибка... по сути у тебя матрица инцидентности транспонированная: по строкам там рёбра, а по столбцам — вершины (Си/C++ это не фортран — тут матрицы традиционно — это массив векторов-строк). при выводе ты это учитываешь, а при работе с ней — нет... ну и цикл ` for (int v = 1;v<=Edge;v++)` судя по именам должен быть по вершинам, а не по рёбрам...

Comment: я в упор не понимаю, вроде поменял в проге, а результат тот же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я решил полностью переписать код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int Vertex, Edge;
    cout << "Vertex: ";
    cin >> Vertex;
    cout << "Edge: ";
    cin >> Edge;
    
    int Graph[Vertex][Vertex];
    int Incidence[Vertex][Edge];
    int AR[Edge][Edge];
    int mass[Edge][2];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Vertex; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Vertex; j++){
            Graph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Vertex; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Edge; j++){
            Incidence[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Edge; j++){
            AR[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++){
        cout << "e1=";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "e2=";
        cin >> y;
        cout << endl;
        Graph[x - 1][y - 1] = 1;
        Graph[y - 1][x - 1] = 1;
        mass[i][0] = x - 1;
        mass[i][1] = y - 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++){
        Incidence[mass[i][0]][i] = 1;
        Incidence[mass[i][1]][i] = 1;
    }
    
    for (int v = 0; v < Vertex; v++){
        for (int e0 = 0; e0 < Edge; e0++){
            if (Incidence[v][e0]){
                for(int e1 = e0 + 1; e1 < Edge; e1++){
                    if (Incidence[v][e1]){
                        AR[e0][e1] = 1;
                        AR[e1][e0] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    cout << "\nAdjacency matrix:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Vertex; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Vertex; j++){
            cout << " " << Graph[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "\nIncidence:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Vertex; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Edge; j++){
            cout << " " << Incidence[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nAdjacency matrix of Edge Graph:\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Edge; j++){
            cout << " " << AR[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

И в самом конце я нашел ошибку в вашем коде, во время создания матрицы инцидентности место

```
for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++) {
        Incidence[i][mass[i].x] = 1; // incidence matrix
        Incidence[i][mass[i].y] = 1;
 }
```

надо было писать

```
for (int i = 0; i < Edge; i++) {
        Incidence[mass[i].x][i] = 1; // incidence matrix
        Incidence[mass[i].y][i] = 1;
 }
```